# Tooltip following a cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I created a tooltip which appears when you hover over the icon, but only problem is that it's not following a cursor and because of that it can become stuck sometimes.

Here is a working example: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7RjqA/)

Here my code:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/JkhlPKF.png"><span>Equipment</span></a>
<a href="#" class="tooltip"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/lgHQamk.png"><span>Maps</span></a>
```

**CSS**

```css
.tooltip {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
}
.tooltip:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
}
.tooltip span {
    display: none;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #FFFFCC;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

If it's not possible via CSS, is it possible with simple JavaScript (not jQuery, project that I'm working on doesn't allow using jQuery)?

Thanks.

Comment: What is it not doing that you'd like it to do? The tooltip seems to be appearing on mouse hover. Not sure what you mean by "following a cursor"

Comment: I mean that if you hover over the image, that tooltip apperas but also follows the mouse, so that tooltip moves as you move a cursor. In some situations where icons are under each other, it happens that you can't hover over the second icon because tooltip got over it. That tooltip shoul be connected to the end of mouse.

Comment: You can see an example here http://itsmeara.com/jquery/atooltip/ when you hover over "Normal Tooltip " demo. But it's in jquery, so I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

In *pure* CSS it's nearly impossible to create a solution. But maybe this is something for you: Create a wrapper-span around the description-tag and display it as block on relative position, z-index minus one (z-index of the describtion minus one). And add the rule, that on hovering the wrapper the describtion is display as an block.
`<a href="#" class="tooltip"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/JkhlPKF.png"><span class="wrapper"><span class="describe">Equipment</span></span></a>`

I created an example (based on yours): http://jsfiddle.net/T2YxQ/